# New roof with broken old plywood visible from attic

Tags: roof

Visible broken old plywood spot from inside attic. Roofer claimed new roof passed inspection and this spot doesn't impact the roof. Can see the nail didn't penetrate into the joint as he nail it down with a new plywood on top of old one.
Can I ask him to redo the roof or what is other solutions ?

[image]

Comment: You could use an angle grinder to cut off the nail if that's what is offending you. Otherwise it doesn't seem reasonable to expect some kind of repair for that little bad spot below the new sheathing. The roof surface will be plenty stiff over that little bit of damage.

Comment: Looks like new plywood installed over old boards. Old roof sheathing boards are frequently dried up, shrunken, and splinter easily when penetrated by nails, and that is not the fault of the roofers.

Comment: "Can I ask him to redo the roof" Absolutely! But you'll probably get laughed at.

Comment: That one nail was possibly driven there for an entirely different purpose other than holding the plywood down, maybe to keep something from sliding off the roof. I am sure it was not intended to hold it to the rafters. I say that because it is only one nail, not a whole row of them like they were trying to nail to a rafter.